# Problem when saving json data into python list

Tags: python, json

I'm trying to get two attributes at the time from my json data and add them as an item on my python list. However, when trying to add those two: `['emailTypeDesc']['createdDate']`  it throws an error. Could someone help with this? thanks in advance!

json:

```
{
'readOnly': False,
'senderDetails': {'firstName': 'John', 'lastName': 'Doe', 'emailAddress': 'johndoe@gmail.com', 'emailAddressId': 123456, 'personalId': 123, 'companyName': 'ACME‘},
'clientDetails': {'firstName': 'Jane', 'lastName': 'Doe', 'emailAddress': 'janedoe@gmail.com', 'emailAddressId': 654321, 'personalId': 456, 'companyName': 'Lorem Ipsum‘}},
'notesSection': {},
'emailList': [{'requestId': 12345667, 'emailId': 9876543211, 'emailType': 3, 'emailTypeDesc': 'Email-In', 'emailTitle': 'SampleTitle 1', 'createdDate': '15-May-2020 11:15:52', 'fromMailList': [{'firstName': 'Jane', 'lastName': 'Doe', 'emailAddress': 'janedoe@gmail.com',}]},
          {'requestId': 12345667, 'emailId': 14567775, 'emailType': 3, 'emailTypeDesc': 'Email-Out', 'emailTitle': 'SampleTitle 2', 'createdDate': '16-May-2020 16:15:52', 'fromMailList': [{'firstName': 'Jane', 'lastName': 'Doe', 'emailAddress': 'janedoe@gmail.com',}]},
          {'requestId': 12345667, 'emailId': 12345, 'emailType': 3, 'emailTypeDesc': 'Email-In', 'emailTitle': 'SampleTitle 3', 'createdDate': '17-May-2020 20:15:52', 'fromMailList': [{'firstName': 'Jane', 'lastName': 'Doe', 'emailAddress': 'janedoe@gmail.com',}]   
}
```

python:

```
final_list = []

data = json.loads(r.text)
myId = [(data['emailList'][0]['requestId'])]
for each_req in myId:
    final_list.append(each_req)
myEmailList = [mails['emailTypeDesc']['createdDate'] for mails in data['emailList']]
for each_requ in myEmailList:
    final_list.append(each_requ)
return final_list
```

This error comes up when I run the above code:

```
TypeError: string indices must be integers
```

Desired output for `final_list`:

```
[12345667, 'Email-In', '15-May-2020 11:15:52',  'Email-Out', '16-May-2020 16:15:52', 'Email-In', '17-May-2020 20:15:52']
```

My problem is definetely in this line:

```
myEmailList = [mails['emailTypeDesc']['createdDate'] for mails in data['emailList']]
```

because when I run this without the second attribute `['createdDate']` it would work, but I need both attributes on my `final_list`:

```
  myEmailList = [mails['emailTypeDesc'] for mails in data['emailList']]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're misunderstanding the syntax. `mails['emailTypeDesc']['createdDate']` is looking for the key `'createdDate'` *inside* the object `mails['emailTypeDesc']`, but in fact they are two items at the same level.

Since `mails['emailTypeDesc']` is a string, not a dictionary, you get the error you have quoted. It seems that you want to add the two items `mails['emailTypeDesc']` and `mails['createdDate']` to your list. I'm not sure if you'd rather join these together into a single string or create a sub-list or something else. Here's a sublist option.

```
myEmailList = [[mails['emailTypeDesc'], mails['createdDate']] for mails in data['emailList']]
```

Answer (score 0):

Strings in JSON must be in double quotes, not single.

Edit: As well as names.